# Como exibir um vídeo utilizando o ExoPlayer?

Tags: android

Estou tentando implementar o exemplo mais simples do ExoPlayer ([**link projeto**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html) e [Link do Tutorial do Projeto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6VjF638VObA)). Porém, após seguir todos os passos do tutorial, a aplicação roda, mas não exibe nenhum sinal de funcionamento do vídeo.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private VideoSurfaceView surfaceView;
private Surface surface;

public static final String TAG = "VodExoPlayer";

private ExoPlayer exoPlayer;
private DefaultSampleSource sampleSource;
private MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer videoTrackRenderer;
private MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer audioTrackRenderer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setParameters();

    builderExoPlayer();
}

private void setParameters() {
    surfaceView = (VideoSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);

    surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);
}

private void builderExoPlayer() {
    int numRenderers = 2;
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.semanticdevlab.com/abc.mp4");

    sampleSource = new DefaultSampleSource(new FrameworkSampleExtractor(getApplicationContext(), uri, null), numRenderers);

    videoTrackRenderer = new MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer(sampleSource, MediaCodec.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT);
    audioTrackRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(sampleSource);

    exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Factory.newInstance(numRenderers);

    exoPlayer.prepare(videoTrackRenderer, audioTrackRenderer);

    exoPlayer.sendMessage(videoTrackRenderer, MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer.MSG_SET_SURFACE, surface);

    exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    exoPlayer.release();
}


/**
 * Métodos Abaixo surgiram de "surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this)" com SurfaceHolder.Callback
 */

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    surface = holder.getSurface();
    Log.i(TAG, "Surface created...");
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    //Nada a fazer
    Log.i(TAG, "Surface changed...");
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    surface = null;
    Log.i(TAG, "Surface destroyed...");
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<com.google.android.exoplayer.VideoSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surface"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Como eu disse, não há nenhum sinal de funcionamento do vídeo nem na tela e nem no LogCat.

Alguém poderia me indicar se há algo errado ou faltando no código?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depois de alguns dias tentando, consegui a solução! Praticamente não há material sobre o ExoPlayer em português.

No código **MainActivity.java**, toda a configuração do ExoPlayer está correta, porém a linha `exoPlayer.release();` não deve ser executada, pois ela finaliza o Player. Assim, basta retira-la:

```
private void builderExoPlayer() {
int numRenderers = 2;
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.semanticdevlab.com/abc.mp4");

sampleSource = new DefaultSampleSource(new FrameworkSampleExtractor(getApplicationContext(), uri, null), numRenderers);

videoTrackRenderer = new MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer(sampleSource, MediaCodec.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT);
audioTrackRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(sampleSource);

exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Factory.newInstance(numRenderers);

exoPlayer.prepare(videoTrackRenderer, audioTrackRenderer);

exoPlayer.sendMessage(videoTrackRenderer, MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer.MSG_SET_SURFACE, surface);

exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
}
```

**O código XML e o MANIFEST estão corretos**.